# How to align js clock to center of page?

Tags: css, image, center

How do I align a javascript countdown box to the center of the page? The url is where the js is located is http://www.freelanceseohelp.com/offer/mobile/index.html

I tried aligning the following but I'm having problems:

```
.flip-clock-wrapper {
```

I tried adding the above to

```
<div class="clock"></div>
```

Any help fixing this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your post is incomplete. please update it

Answer (score 17):

I'm pretty late to the party here but the following works for me at the time of writing (Version: 0.7.4 Beta). The idea is to wrap it in a container and override some of it's CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flip-clock"></div>
    <!-- Flip clock is attached the this element, not .container -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.flip-clock {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

By default `.flip-clock` has `width: 100%` and `display: block`. By setting `width: auto` and `display: inline-block` the item no longer spans the width of it's parent and is able to be centered by adding `text-align: center` to it's container.

Comment: Went to google to find the same thing and your container div helped me solve the same problem. Upvoted!

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Comment: You saved me big time, much love

Answer (score 1):

through testing, i determined the width of the widget is 460px when considering margin. here is the css to make it happen.

```
.flip-clock-wrapper{
  max-width: 460px;
  margin: 3em auto 2em;
}
```

I also added top margin of 3em and bottom margin of 2em to align it correctly. that page has a ton of problems with the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
.flip-clock-wrapper {
  /* text-align: center; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* width: 100%; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 460px;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

> Remove the Commented CSS in the above CSS Class and add the rest 3 lines in your CSS class to get your Page like Below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add new div element with specify `display: inline-block;` to archive this.

```
<div class="clock flip-clock-wrapper">
     <div class="middle">            // Add div element (opening)
         ....
         ....
         ....
     </div>                          // Add div element (closing) 
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.middle{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* IE*/
    *zoom:1;/* IE*/
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
.flip-clock-wrapper {
   display: table;     //added
}

.flip-clock-divider {
   float: left; // remove
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
   float: left;           // remove
   display: inline-block; // added
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this is your css-

```
.flip-clock-wrapper{
   width:460px;
   margin:1em auto;
}
```

I hope I'll helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just decrease the width of your clock wrapper & set margin value.

```
.flip-clock-wrapper{
    width: 480px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
.flip-clock-wrapper{
  max-width:480px;
  margin:3em auto;
}
```

Comment: the answer is incorrect. the max width of the element is 460px, not 480px. you also merely parroted the rest of the answers here, which makes the upvote your answer received seem entirely suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Using the .js file from a CDN I did not wanted to edit it.

I applied those lines to my website main CSS:

```
.flip-clock-wrapper {
    width: inherit !important;
}

.flip-clock {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="clock" style="margin:Inherited;"></div>
      <div class="message"></div>   
      <script type="text/javascript">
        code!!!
      </script>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would help the questioner if you explained the method or technique you used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `.flip-clock-wrapper` contain `width:auto` and `display:inline-block`. That is:

```
.flip-clock-wrapper {
    text-align: center !important;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```